# Using Select.Select in Python 2.4.3, how to indentify the port that data was received from?

Tags: python, sockets, select

Below is an example of a socket server from the internet. You can see I am modify the code to use two different ports. Each port will have different code behind it. How can I check which port I received the data on? Different data will come on each port. Thanks!

```
# Socket server in python using select function

import socket, select

CONNECTION_LIST = []    # list of socket clients
RECV_BUFFER = 4096 # Advisable to keep it as an exponent of 2
PORT = 502
PORT2 = 5000

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# this has no effect, why ?
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", PORT))
server_socket.listen(10)

server_socket1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# this has no effect, why ?
server_socket1.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket1.bind(("0.0.0.0", PORT2))
server_socket1.listen(10)

# Add server socket to the list of readable connections
CONNECTION_LIST.append(server_socket)
CONNECTION_LIST.append(server_socket1)

print "Chat server started on port " + str(PORT)

while 1:
    # Get the list sockets which are ready to be read through select
    read_sockets,write_sockets,error_sockets = select.select(CONNECTION_LIST,[],[])

    for sock in read_sockets:

        #New connection
        if sock == server_socket1:
            print "Modbus socket"

        elif sock == server_socket:
            # Handle the case in which there is a new connection recieved through server_socket
            sockfd, addr = server_socket.accept()
            CONNECTION_LIST.append(sockfd)
            print "Client (%s, %s) connected" % addr

        #Some incoming message from a client
        else:
            # Data recieved from client, process it
            try:
                #In Windows, sometimes when a TCP program closes abruptly,
                # a "Connection reset by peer" exception will be thrown
# How can I know which port data is from?
                data = sock.recv(RECV_BUFFER)
                # echo back the client message
                if data:
                    sock.send('OK ... ' + data)

            # client disconnected, so remove from socket list
            except:
                broadcast_data(sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline" % addr)
                print "Client (%s, %s) is offline" % addr
                sock.close()
                CONNECTION_LIST.remove(sock)
                continue

server_socket.close()
server_socket1.close()
```

Comment: Why are you using Python 2.4.3? It's more than a decade old and has been superseded by a bug fix, three minor versions and a major version.

Comment: This is Digi Connect embedded, they not offer newer. In fact, we hoping they upgrade.